# ImportError with different python installations.

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I am getting below ImportError while running a python file.

> ImportError: No module named osgeo.gdal_array

```
!/usr/bin/env python
from osgeo.gdal_array import BandReadAsArray
```

However, if i try to import same from command line, it runs fine.

```
$ which python
/home/hduser/anaconda2/bin/python

$ python
>>> from osgeo.gdal_array import BandReadAsArray
>>>
```

Also, please see the below where i am getting the same ImportError.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7
>>> from osgeo.gdal_array import BandReadAsArray
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named osgeo.gdal_array
```

I figured out that there is something going on between different versions of python. But, i do not want to change the original source code.

How do i make my program run without changing anything within the code of calling python installed in anaconda explicitly?

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/bin/env python --version`?

Comment: `Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

Comment: Did you install `gdal` using pip or conda?

Comment: I did using `conda`